# Openseamap on Google Maps Wms Error for Gebco Depth Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, openseamap

I am trying to put some OSM based layers on Google Maps. The project name is [openseamap](http://map.openseamap.org/). So far it works fine until zoom 8. But after zoom 8 I am getting 400 error which says "400: X,Y values for the tile index were calculated to be {120.99999999902559, 155.83725643764348} which had to be rounded to {121, 156} and exceeds the threshold of 10%. Perhaps the client is using the wrong origin ?"

```
var gebcoLayer =
                new google.maps.ImageMapType(
                    {

                        getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                            // Compose URL for overlay tile
                            var tilesPerGlobe = 1 << zoom;
                            var x = coord.x % tilesPerGlobe;
                            if (x < 0) {
                                x = tilesPerGlobe + x;
                            }
                            var s = Math.pow(2, zoom);
                            var twidth = 256;
                            var theight = 256;


                            var gBl = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x * twidth / s, (coord.y + 1) * theight / s)); // bottom left / SW
                            var gTr = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((x + 1) * twidth / s, coord.y * theight / s)); // top right / NE



                            var mercator1 = Conv.ll2m(gBl.lng(), gBl.lat());
                            var mercator2 = Conv.ll2m(gTr.lng(), gTr.lat());


                            var bbox2 = mercator1.x + "," + mercator1.y + "," + mercator2.x + "," + mercator2.y;                           


                            var url = "http://osm.franken.de:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?LAYERS=gebco_2014&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=" + bbox2 + "&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256";
                            return url;
                        },
                        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                        name: "Gebco",
                        isPng: true,
                        //maxZoom: 18,
                        opacity: 0.3,
                    });
            map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, gebcoLayer);
```

Instead of typing the whole code here I created a fiddle.
[Here is my fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/bulutkartal/g99pcfgz/)

As you can see in fiddle, it works fine if the zoom value is smaller than 8. I couldn't figure out what causes this error. I am assuming the zoom level difference between osm and google? or the way I calculate bbox value?

Comment: I am glad some ppl liked the question but any solution for this? :)